# Android, native memory use in dumpsys meminfo

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I can't seem to find any information to help me understand the memory readings from meinfo. My application loads a bunch of images, uses them, and then when the view is switched it should get rid of them and get some new images.

The meminfo output shows the native size as increasing as my application goes on. Allocated goes up and down (although very little) throughout and free remains faitly low.

THe app starts at about 10k native size and by the time it reaches the finish it's 31k. Does this indicate a potential memory leak or is this related to some form of caching?

I recycle my bitmaps after I finish with them and I null the views that hold them when finished with them. I can't understand where (if at all) I may be going wrong.

Can anyone offer advice on the meaning (and my interpretation) of this information?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android